# Parse XML file in Python 2.x

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an XML file songs.xml as partially shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Event status="happened">
<Song title="Erase and rewind">
<Artist name="The Cardigans" ID="340900">
</Artist>
<Info StartTime="22:22:13" JazlerID="8310" 
 PlayListerID="" />
</Song>
</Event>
```

I need to parse such file and get all the fields like:
Song Title:
Artist:
Start Time:
ID:

I try something like this but I get only the title of each song:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

# Open XML document using minidom parser
DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("songs.xml")
Event  = DOMTree.documentElement
if Event.hasAttribute("happened"):
   print "Root element : %s" % collection.getAttribute("happened")

# Get all the songs in the collection
songs = Event.getElementsByTagName("Song")
x = Event.getElementsByTagName("*").length
print x

# Print detail of each song.
for song in songs:
   print "*****Song*****"
   if song.hasAttribute("title"):
      print "Title: %s" % song.getAttribute("title")
```

I need this to save them later in a db
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse XML files:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('songs.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)

    for x in child:
        print(x.tag, x.attrib)
```

Which prints out:

```
Song {'title': 'Erase and rewind'}
Artist {'name': 'The Cardigans', 'ID': '340900'}
Info {'StartTime': '22:22:13', 'JazlerID': '8310', 'PlayListerID': ''}
```

Where the XML tags are printed on the left, and the data stored in dictionaries printed on the right. You can access the data from these dictionaries.

If you want to only print the values that are not `None` or empty string, you can try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

tree = ET.parse('songs.xml') 
root = tree.getroot() 

for child in root:
    title = child.attrib.get("title")
    if title:
        print('title = %s' % title)

    for x in child:
        for key in x.attrib:
            value = x.attrib.get(key)
            if value:
                print(key, "=", value)
```

Which gives:

```
title = Erase and rewind
name = The Cardigans
ID = 340900
StartTime = 22:22:13
JazlerID = 8310
```

Answer (score 1):

The final answer that serves my need, based on RoadRunners suggestion is the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('songs1.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


for child in root:
    #print(child.tag, child.attrib)
    #print(child.attrib.get("title"))


    print(child.attrib.get("title"))

    for x in child:
        if x.tag == "Artist":
            print(x.tag)
            #print(dic_artist)
            dic_artist = x.attrib
            print(dic_artist.get("name"))
            print(dic_artist.get("ID"))
        if x.tag == "Info":
            print(x.tag)
            #print(dic_info)
            dic_info = x.attrib
            print(dic_info.get("StartTime"))
            print(dic_info.get("JazlerID"))
            #print(dic_info.get("PlayListerID"))
    print("-------------------------------")
```